# How do I install my dual graphics card drivers?

Tags: drivers, amd-processor, dual-graphics

I want to install my dual graphics card drivers, but I have no idea what I’m doing and I’m not really sure what I’ve done so far.

My laptop’s specs:

- AMD a8 4500m 1.9 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- Radeon dual grahpics HD 7640g + 7470m
- Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I have actually messed with installing different graphics drivers in Ubuntu for correct CUDA / OpenCL support, and I have to tell you it is no easy task to perform.

You can try:

1. Install [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) - this is a library of usefull extensions for you Ubuntu
2. Check if your cards are supported, by default Ubuntu uses open source amd gfx driver.
3. Try manually installing [AMD Catalyst](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

---

There is no easy answer to this question so get ready to spend couple hours on those tasks.

BTW I play LOL on Ubuntu and it works well just as it is on default drivers via PlayOnLinux